# "AADSTS500113: No reply address is registered for the application". when used with Azure API Management, OAuth 2.0 authorization with Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

I followed the steps from the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad

But I get an error below even when the `Redirect URIs` of the **client** app has been provided:

> Request Id: a58c1fe8-7d64-42b5-8603-5d2e66b45a02
>
> Correlation Id: 65faea2b-9a2b-435c-a527-c689113417e8
>
> Timestamp: 2021-08-16T16:24:58Z
>
> Message: AADSTS500113: No reply address is registered for the application.

[image]

Please note that v1 of endpoints are used instead of v2 from the same link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#enable-oauth-20-user-authorization-in-the-developer-console

**Anyone** who is able to set up based on the steps on the doc?

Comment: Could you please share your API management configuration ?

Comment: sure, which parts you want me to share?

Comment: Invalid client secret is provided so did you provide a client secret ?

Comment: yes, both client id and client secret are provided. I check three times based on the steps on the doc. but still failed.

Comment: Can you check the secret on the app registration blade ? or generate a new one and see if working with a new one

Comment: I have tried that before I posted the question, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your correlation ID and saw that there is no reply URL set for the ApplicationID listed. I don't want to list your Application ID publicly but I would search for that and confirm that you are accessing the same app where you have set the reply URL. It looks like the one you are looking at in the portal might be a different application.

Once you add the correct RedirectURL/ReplyURL to the corresponding App Registration of that app it should work fine.

Comment: as you can see from the screenshot, the reply URL has been setup on the client app in App Registration. Anything I should check and change to make it work?

Comment: Sorry, just saw this now. Have you tried creating a new client secret and copied the right client secret value? Sometimes it needs a renewal if you are getting that error.

Comment: Is it possible to use a Managed Identity instead of a password? If so, please provide a link. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and confirmed with my IT department many times that the redirectURI was configured correctly in Azure App Services

Turns out we needed to add login.microsoft.com to the allowed CORS list
After allowing that site the application worked as expected